# silverstripe overwrite function of dataobject

Tags: silverstripe

I want to extend the DataObject (EditableDateField) of a module that I use (UserDefinedForms). There I want to overwrite a certain method (getFormField). I was trying to extend with [DataExtension](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataextension). But it does not work.

Here the code...

**config.php**:

```
EditableDateField::add_extension("CustomEditableDateField");
```

**CustomEditableDateField**:

```
class CustomEditableDateField extends DataExtension {
    public function getFormField() {
        //test is function called
        echo 'test';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Also I tried to use Object::useCustomClass in the config to replace the whole EditableDateField with my CustomClass, but also no success.

What is the best way to do that?

Many thanx,
Florian

Comment: by overriding `getFormField` what are you trying to do? Might be another function that you can use and has a `extend` callback?

Comment: i want to do this and force always the same dateformat in a multilingual website: 

public function getFormField() {
  $defaultValue = ($this->getSetting('DefaultToToday')) ? date('Y-m-d') : $this->Default;
  $field = new DateField( $this->Name, $this->Title, $defaultValue);
  $field->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
        **$field->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd.MM.yyyy');**
  return $field;
 }

Comment: not a 100% sure but then just to set the dateformat couldn't you use the onBeforeRender callback on your extension?

Comment: thx. the basic problem is that the function in the extension is not called. if I read the documentation of DataExtension again, I wonder if it is actually possible to just overwrite an existing method.

Comment: I don't think you can overwrite anything you want, DataExtension have special hooks called by extend() on the original class, on FormFields onBeforeRender is the only hook being call on extensions. If you want to overwrite any function you'll have to create a custom class that extends EditableDateField.

Comment: I also tried with a custom class that extends EditableDateField. But then I don´t know how to tell silverstripe to use that class instead of the original one. I tried with Object::useCustomClass('EditableDateField', 'CustomEditableDateField'); but it does not work and I do not find any docs about that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are wanting to achieve, you don't need to extend `EditableDateField`.

What you are looking for is `EditableDateField_FormField` which extends `DateField`. `DateField` does the heavy lifting for generating the HTML and doing the validation etc. One thing that `DateField` does have is a static variable called `default_config` [which looks like this:](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-DateField.html#64)

```php
static $default_config = array(
    'showcalendar' => false,
    'jslocale' => null,
    'dmyfields' => false,
    'dmyseparator' => '&nbsp;<span class="separator">/</span>&nbsp;',
    'dmyplaceholders' => true,
    'dateformat' => null,
    'datavalueformat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    'min' => null,
    'max' => null,
);
```

Using the configuration system in Silverstripe, you can change the default `dateformat` to your `dd.MM.yyyy` format by using:

```
EditableDateField_FormField:
  default_config:
    'dateformat': 'dd.MM.yyyy'
```

You will want to use `EditableDateField_FormField` like my example above rather than change the `default_config` of `DateField` itself otherwise you may encounter issues in the CMS.

#### Technical Description

This works due to [the constructor of `DateField` setting the instance config to the value of the `default_config`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-DateField.html#98).

Because the value of `dateformat` is normally `NULL` in `default_config`, [an if-statement passes](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-DateField.html#99) which causes `dateformat` to be set the result from `i18n::get_date_format()`.