# Silverstripe extend DataObject via subclass

Tags: php, subclass, silverstripe

Similar question as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290802/silverstripe-overwrite-function-of-dataobject). How do I extend/customize a function in a dataobject via subclassing?

I have created a custom class:

```
class CustomEditableFormField extends EditableFormField
{
    public function getFieldConfiguration()
    {
        //Do custom stuff       
    }
}
```

I then added:

```
Injector:
  EditableFormField:
    class: CustomEditableFormField
```

In my config.yml but the subclass is still being ignored. Do I need to include all the functions of EditableFormField like an interface, or is there something bigger I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the field is created statically with create() rather than new.

eg. Use EditableFormField::create() instead of new EditableFormField();

Also, make sure you flush or the YAML changes won't take effect.